# Remove <style> tag and <script> tag from plain HTML using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my plain HTML code.

```
<style>
 /* style tag goes here*/
</style>
<form method="POST" action="#" id="_form_93_" class="_form _form_93 _inline-form  _dark" novalidate>
  <input type="hidden" name="u" value="93" />
  <input type="hidden" name="f" value="93" />
  <input type="hidden" name="s" />
  <input type="hidden" name="c" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="m" value="0" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
// script tag goes here
</script>
```

I want to remove `<style></style>` and `<script></script>` tag from HTML code so expected result will be.

```html
<form method="POST" action="#" id="_form_93_" class="_form _form_93 _inline-form  _dark" novalidate>
  <input type="hidden" name="u" value="93" />
  <input type="hidden" name="f" value="93" />
  <input type="hidden" name="s" />
  <input type="hidden" name="c" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="m" value="0" />
</form>
```

Comment: Why ? Do not write `css` and `script` then!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/remove

Comment: @Rayon Actually this is autoresponder html code and i just want <form></form> code.

Comment: Is this in a running HTML page? If so, just use `elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);` Or do you only have this for a source?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan's answer is perfect for what you want to achieve.

Comment: why did u write `style` and `script` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the tags using this

```
$('style, script').remove();
```

Styles will no longer show on screen and both HTML elements will dissapear from the DOM.

BUT, javascript code will still be executed if events have been attached before running the `remove()` code.

If you're only looking to clean some code returning by an ajax call (for example), it will work fine. If you want to clear the styles and javascript from the page you're already in, some Javascript code might already be attached to elements before you remove the `script` tag.

[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccsx15re/) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

> **Using jQuery:**

```
jQuery('style').remove();

jQuery('script').remove();
```

> **Using Plain JavaScript:**

```
window.onload = function(){
    var getStyle = document.getElementsByTagName("style");
    getStyle[0].remove();
    var getScript = document.getElementsByTagName("script"); 
    getScript[0].remove();
}
```

Please find a working fiddle, which shows how to delete h1 tag, [**Link**](https://jsfiddle.net/bhatnagar018/wnghxwfu/)